# Error 5123 in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I changed my windows. But I can not attach `mdf,ldf` files and cannot move or copy them.

My error is:

> Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>   An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5 (Access is denied) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'D:\Project\Masoomi\UniversityService\DataBase\Universityservice.mdf'. (Microsoft SQL Server, **Error: 5123**)

I run as administrator too. My windows is 7 and I installed SQL Server 2008 R2.

My previous windows was 7 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

What shall I do?

Comment: Does the directory exist? Also, I doubt the database itself is running as admin, so check which user it's running as.

Comment: maybe file in use, or permissions! also checks the target database files, SQL server is not as smart to creates not exist folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shared the mdf,ldf files and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

As another solution I came across this today and was able to resolve it by simply running SQL Server Management Studio as administrator. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.